# Vaadin 24 - Problem Binding ENUM Roles to CheckboxGroup

Tags: vaadin, vaadin24

I'm new to both Vaadin and Java - so sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm using the User and Role entities from the default starter - and I'm trying to create a checkbox group of the enum roles - but I'm banging my head against a wall.

Here's what I've tried:

```
CheckBoxGroup<Role> roleCheckBoxGroup = new CheckBoxGroup<>("Roles", DataProvider.ofItems(Role.values()));
```

Result: The IDE complains and wants me to create a new class "CheckBoxGroup" (even though I've already imported the Vaadin Component - import com.vaadin.flow.component.checkbox.CheckboxGroup).

Next up:

```
CheckboxGroup<Role> roleCheckbox = new CheckboxGroup<>();
 roleCheckbox.setDataProvider(new ListDataProvider<>(Arrays.asList(Phone.values())));
```

Result: The IDE doesn't know what "asList" means and wants to search the Maven repository.

I feel like I'm "close" - but these are *literally* the only two examples I could find on the Interwebs.

I would really appreciate it if one of you kind folks could point me in the right direction.

BTW: I did review: [Binding List<Enum> to CheckBoxGroup in vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863202/binding-listenum-to-checkboxgroup-in-vaadin) - that was one of the two examples. It appears as if it doesn't work for Vaadin 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it:

```
CheckboxGroup<Role> roleCheckbox = new CheckboxGroup<>();
roleCheckbox.setItems(Role.values());
binder.forField(roleCheckbox).bind(User::getRoles, User::setRoles);
```

I hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: You can use `Role.values()` directly there, setItems has convenience overloading for that.

Answer (score 1):

Value of the `CheckBoxGroup` and all other multiselect fields in Vaadin is `Set`. Thus you can't directly bind it to property of type `List`. So you either need to change the property type or use `withConverter` and write converter from presentation type `Set` to model type `List`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see that CheckboxGroup uses ".setItems". I don't know how to get or format the Role ENUM into a format that it will accept.